# Magento 2 : how to add extension attribute to filter?

Tags: magento2, interface

[image]

how to add extension attribute to to filter ?

I am getting items if i remove my custom filter.
But i want to add my extension_attributes in searchCriteriaBuilder to check further condition.

Here is `extension_attributes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface">
        <attribute code="parent_product_id" type="int">
            <join reference_table="catalog_product_bundle_selection" reference_field="product_id" join_on_field="entity_id">
                <field>parent_product_id</field>
            </join>
        </attribute>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Comment: $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('sku', '%' . $sku . '%', 'like');

Comment: SKU is fine. But i have problem with extension attribute which i defined in extension_attributes.xml

Comment: Did you try `extension_attribute_parent_product_id.parent_product_id` in in the marked code? You use an underscore as separator between table alias and field name. Imho that must be a dot.

Comment: Yes i also tried with it. but it is showing invalid attribute name.
"message": "Invalid attribute name: %1",
    "parameters": [
        "extension_attribute_parent_product_id.parent_product_id"
    ],